# Where can I find sample product data for demo purposes?

Tags: products

I'm looking for a product catalog of sample products mainly electronics and clothing that I can use to showcase in demo applications, e-commerce themes, etc.

Any ideas of sources that would be suitable to use for this purpose without copyright issues?
I mean even sample data that don't refer to real products but with images would be fine.

The format could be json,csv,xls and they should at the very least have

- name
- description
- image
- category
- brand